# Why is the data parameter in Gl.BufferSubData() method of OpenGL.NET an IntPtr?

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm making a Game Engine in c# using OpenGL.NET. Right now I am working on a Batch Renderer. A staple method of a Batch Renderer is glBufferSubData(). But the actual data I am providing is in form of a QuadVertex[] whereas the method asks for an IntPtr!! What should the IntPtr be?? In C++ we can provide a void* there and in Java(LWJGL3), a FloatBuffer. Is there a way to convert my QuadVertex[] to an IntPtr?
Here is the QuadVertex class:

```
internal sealed class QuadVertex
{
    public vec3 Position;
    public vec4 Colour;
    public vec2 TexCoord;

    public static uint GetSize()
    {
        return (3 + 4 + 2) * 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [OpenGL.Net](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net) `Gl.BufferSubData` is overloaded. The data argument has to be of type `IntPtr` or of type `object`.
The method delegates to [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml), where the argument specifies a pointer to a consecutive byte array which contains the data.

For instance the argument can either be an array (of any type, e.g.: `float`):

```
var data = new float[] { ... };
Gl.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(0), (uint)(4 * data.Length), data);
```

Or you have to create some unmanaged memory ([`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=netcore-3.1)) and to copy some data ([`Marshal.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netcore-3.1)) to the memory:

```
IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(..., 0, unmanagedPointer, size);
Gl.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(0), size, unmanagedPointer);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
```

---

Alternatively think about [Buffer Mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) ([`glMapBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml)).

Comment: Thanks as usual Rabbid!!

Comment: But I have to ask why there is an overload accepting an IntPtr?

Comment: @PixelRifts It is common to use `IntPtr` for a pointer to a bunch of (unmanaged) data. What else would you prefer?

Comment: Ummm... Not having an IntPtr. :) LOL

Comment: @PixelRifts The method just wraps the `glBufferSubData` driver function, where as the data has to be a pointer to memory containing the data (`void*` in C/C++). The most obvious solution is to use `IntPtr`. Other libraries such as [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/) offer a variety of other options, but all the overloaded methods have to linearize the data to byte array and pass a pointer to the array to `glBufferSubData`.